# Why is my foreach loop not matching the keys in users.json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to set a login script using PHP and JSON(No database) but i keep have this errors

> Warning: Use of undefined constant Email - assumed 'Email' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\networth-app\index.php on line 37
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\networth-app\index.php on line 37
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant Email - assumed 'Email' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\networth-app\index.php on line 37

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $msg = '';

    /* Trigger when the login btn is clicked */
    if (isset($_POST['log'])) {

        /* Fetch users.json file */
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("users.json"), true);

        /* Get form data */
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pwd = $_POST['password'];

        /* Form validation */
        if (empty($email || $pwd)) {
            $msg = 'Please fill in all fields';
        } elseif (strlen($pwd) < 5) {
            $msg = 'Password must be more than 5 charcter.';
        } else {
            /* loop through the users.json data */
            foreach ($data as $user) {
                /* Login the user */
                if ($email === $user['Email'] && $pwd === $user['Password']) {
                    $_SESSION['Name'] = $user['Name'];
                    header('location: home.php');
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

users.json

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Name": "Frank Spencer",
            "Email": "fraspecx@mail.com",
            "Password": "test"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Guy Daniel",
            "Email": "guyb@gmail.com",
            "Password": "test1"
        }
    ],
    "user": null
}
```

I want to be able to login to my home.php and echo session name

Comment: You should provide your json object

Comment: ok @MorganFreeFarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "Name": "Frank Spencer",
```

So you would access it like:

```
foreach ($data['users'] as $user) {
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have wrongly used the json data.

Just look at the $**user** variable in foreach loop.

You're using it wrongly, because you're appending to it (with dots (.)) some kind of Email constant, which logically doesn't exist in your file.

You should have something like that (of course check, if the "Email" or "Password" array keys are correctly written):

```
if ($email === $user["Email"] && $pwd === $user["Password"]) {
```

Comment: i did that but im still having <Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\xampp\htdocs\networth-app\index.php on line 37>

Answer (score 0):

when you decode the user.json , it convert to array , so if you want to access any array key directly just to need to write like the $user['Email'] not $user.Email, and also change the $user.Password to $user['Password']
So you need to update your foreach like this

```
foreach ($data as $users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if(isset($user['Email'],$user['Password'])) {
            if ($email === $user['Email'] && $pwd === $user['Password']) {
                $_SESSION['Name'] = $user['Name'];
                header('location: home.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

because you are trying to fetch Email index directly

Comment: i did that but im still having <Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\xampp\htdocs\networth-app\index.php on line 37>